# JavaScript, Trying to get buttons to move on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
/*
var young_link = {
    power: 30,
    cpower: 20,
    hp: 3,
    image: "../images/young_link.jpg",
};


var young_zelda = {
    power: 30,
    cpower: 20,
    hp: 3,
}


var impa = {
    power: 30,
    cpower: 20,
    hp: 3,
}


var hey = {
    power: 30,
    cpower: 20,
    hp: 3,
}

//$("#test").html(young_link);

console.log(young_link);*/


$(document).ready(function() {

    var hero_image = new Array();
    hero_image[0] = new Image();
    hero_image[0].src = 'assets/images/link.png';
    hero_image[0].id = 'image';

    hero_image[1] = new Image();
    hero_image[1].src = 'assets/images/bongo.png';
    hero_image[1].id = 'image';

    hero_image[2] = new Image();
    hero_image[2].src = 'assets/images/gandondorf.jpg';
    hero_image[2].id = 'image';

    hero_image[3] = new Image();
    hero_image[3].src = 'assets/images/queen.png';
    hero_image[3].id = 'image';


    //var test = "<img src= '../images/young_link.jpg'>";

    //var young_hero = ["young_link","young_zelda","impa", "malon"];
    var young_hero = ["Link", "Bongo Bongo","Gandondorf","Queen Gohma"];
    var health = [100, 70, 120, 50];


    for (var i = 0; i < young_hero.length; i++) {
        var hero_btns = $("<buttons>");

        hero_btns.addClass("hero hero_button");

        hero_btns.attr({"data-name":young_hero[i],"data-health":health[i],"data-image":hero_image[i]});


        hero_btns.text(young_hero[i]);
        hero_btns.append(hero_image[i]);
        hero_btns.append(health[i]);

        $("#buttons").append(hero_btns);
    }   




$(".hero_button").on("click" , function() {

    var battle_ground = $("<div>");

    battle_ground.addClass("hero hero_button");

    battle_ground.text($(this).data("data-name"));

    $("#battle").append(battle_ground);

});

});
```

---

The for loop is working and appending the buttons on the screen. But in $(".hero_button").on("click" , function()  it is just putting a empty box on the page with a click. So, it is not taking the data that is attached to the button.

Comment: So the issue is that the data attributes aren't being applied to your new button?

Comment: Perhaps it would be easiest to create a jsFiddle showing your problem

Comment: Yes the data attributes aren't being applied to the new button.

Comment: In your click function you are not giving the newly created element any data attributes as you are in the for loop. These newly created elements will not inherit them as a result of sharing a classname

Comment: Think I see what you are saying. So how do you think I should change that

Comment: Well, for one you are creating `buttons` elements in the for loop, they should be `button`. Secondly when you create a new element in the click handler, you create a `div` so they are a different tag right off the bat. I think you need to copy the element rather than create a new one

Comment: I can also see that you never mark a question as answered, which doesn't motivate people to answer them. When someone provides an answer which solves your issue, you should mark the correct answer

Comment: Also, remove comments from the supplied code if they aren't relevant

Comment: No worries, there is a tick on the left you can click.

Comment: $(".hero_button").on("click" , function() {

 hero_btns = $("<button>");

 hero_btns.addClass("hero hero_button");

 hero_btns.text($(this).data("data-name"));

 $("#battle").append(hero_btns);

});

Comment: I changed the function to copy it but it is not taking the data with it

Comment: also, thank you for telling about marking an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of changes to get the data set and read correctly:

1. make `button` tags instead of `buttons`
2. use `.attr()` instead of `.data()` to get the attributes

See comments inline in the code below.

Also, instead of adding an attribute for the `Image` object of each item (which will add an attribute like `data-image="[Object object]"`) just add an integer corresponding to the iterator index and use that to reference into the `hero_image` array when you need to get the corresponding image.

Additionally, you can use [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the items in the heroes array with a callback function. That way you don't have to worry about updating the iterator variable (`i` in this case) and indexing into the array. You should take a look at this [functional programming guide](http://reactivex.io/learnrx/) which has some good exercises.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var hero_image = new Array();
  hero_image[0] = new Image();
  hero_image[0].src = 'assets/images/link.png';
  hero_image[0].id = 'image';

  hero_image[1] = new Image();
  hero_image[1].src = 'assets/images/bongo.png';
  hero_image[1].id = 'image';

  hero_image[2] = new Image();
  hero_image[2].src = 'assets/images/gandondorf.jpg';
  hero_image[2].id = 'image';

  hero_image[3] = new Image();
  hero_image[3].src = 'assets/images/queen.png';
  hero_image[3].id = 'image';

  var young_heroes = ["Link", "Bongo Bongo", "Gandondorf", "Queen Gohma"];
  var health = [100, 70, 120, 50];
  young_heroes.forEach(function(young_hero,i) {
    var hero_btns = $("<button>");
    hero_btns.addClass("hero hero_button");
    hero_btns.attr({
      "data-name": young_hero,
      "data-health": health[i],
      //instead of adding an attribute for the image object, just add an index
      "data-index": i
    });


    hero_btns.text(young_hero);
    hero_btns.append(hero_image[i]);
    hero_btns.append(health[i]);

    $("#buttons").append(hero_btns);
  });

  $(".hero_button").on("click", function() {
    var battle_ground = $("<div>");
    battle_ground.addClass("hero hero_button");
    //use .attr() here instead of .data()
    battle_ground.text($(this).attr("data-name"));

    /** My additions  - 
     * I am not sure exactly how this should be done  
     * so adjust accordingly 
     **/
    //additionally, you can add attributes to the new battle_ground item
    battle_ground.attr('data-health',$(this).attr("data-health"));

    battle_ground.append(hero_image[$(this).attr("data-index")]);
    battle_ground.append($(this).attr("data-health"));
    /** End my additions **/

    $("#battle").append(battle_ground);
  });
});
```

```css
#battle div {
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons"></div>
Battle ground:
<div id="battle"></div>
```

Comment: That is working. But it is only taking the data-name and not the image or the health

Comment: alright - I updated my code to utilize the `heath` and `index` attributes - see the code between the multi-line comments (i.e. starting with `/** My additions`)

Comment: cool - also see the extra paragraph I added above the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Sam answered your question correctly and rightly deserves the accepted answer. But I wanted to give you an insight into how you can do this in a cleaner way, without lots of arrays which must line up. Also without using jQuery at all. Below you can see a more object oriented way to do this.

You can see it in action [in this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfbmdv5m/)

```
// Now we have an object which represents a hero. No need to duplicate loads of code.
function Hero(heroData) {
    this.name = heroData.name;
  this.health = heroData.health;

  this.setImage = function() {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = heroData.imageSrc;
    this.image.id = heroData.imageId;
  }

  this.createHeroButton = function() {
    this.createButtonElement();
    this.addButtonToPage();
    this.attachButtonEvents();
  }

  this.createButtonElement = function() {
    var heroButton = document.createElement('button');
    heroButton.classList.add('hero,hero_button');
    heroButton.setAttribute('name', this.name);
    heroButton.setAttribute('health', this.health);
    heroButton.appendChild(this.image);
    this.button = heroButton;
  }

  this.attachButtonEvents = function() {
    this.button.addEventListener('click', this.addButtonToPage.bind(this));
  }

  this.addButtonToPage = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.appendChild(this.button);
  }

  this.takeDamage = function(damageValue) {
    this.health -= damageValue;
    this.button.setAttribute('health', this.health);
  }

  this.setImage();
}

// So here we create a Hero instance, in this case Link, we can use now describe links attributes, image, name, health...
var link = new Hero({
    name: 'Link',
  health: 100,
  imageSrc: 'http://orig12.deviantart.net/8bb7/f/2011/276/4/e/four_swords_link_avatar_by_the_missinglink-d4bq8qn.png',
  imageId: 'link-image'
});

var mario = new Hero({
    name: 'Mario',
  health: 100,
  imageSrc: 'http://rs568.pbsrc.com/albums/ss123/stvan000/thumb-super-mario-bros-8bit-Mario.jpg~c200',
  imageId: 'mario-image'
});

// Now we can easily make a button and add it to the page
link.createHeroButton();
mario.createHeroButton();

// Lets try decreasing the health on mario
mario.takeDamage(10);
// Because we have an object reference which handles all of our heros state we can decrease his health and update the buttons data without much trouble.
```

Comment: You're obviously still learning and this is by no means a perfect solution or perfectly written code, but there are some concepts in here which are worth observing. Most importantly I wanted to show you that you don't need jQuery.